# Looking for an Analogous Command to |See for Use in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing, makeidx

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\LARGE
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\addtocontents{toc}{CHAPTERX|see{CHAPTERA}}

\index{ChapterX|see{ChapterA}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the Index

[image]

I would like to produce something similar in the TOC.

However, `|see` doesn't work as nicely (as expected, I guess), for the `\addtocontents` command:

[image]

I tried defining a new command as one would to modify the `|see` xommand for the index, but without success for a TOC entry.

QUESTION: I may I accomplish in the TOC what `|see` does in the index?

Thank you.

Comment: `\addtocontents{toc}{ChapterX, \textit{see}~ChapterA}`

Comment: Thank you @egreg. This works very nicely once I shift the `tableofcontents`  command farther down the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `|see` for `\index` exploits a feature of MakeIndex: whatever follows `|` is written in the `.ind` file preceded by the standard separator and a backslash and followed by the braced page number, so you see

```
\item ChapterX, \see{ChapterA}{2}
```

in the `.ind` file. The standard definition of `\see` discards the second argument.

Since `\tableofcontents` just uses TeX, there is nothing like that. But you can just use `\see` (remember to use a dummy argument).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\MakeRobust{\see}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\addtocontents{toc}{CHAPTERX, \see{CHAPTERA}{}}

Some text

\index{ChapterX|see{ChapterA}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

It's also best to make `\see` robust.

Or you can define your own command.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\DeclareRobustCommand{\tocsee}[1]{\emph{\seename} #1}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\addtocontents{toc}{CHAPTERX, \tocsee{CHAPTERA}}

Some text

\index{ChapterX|see{ChapterA}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A question if I may---In your first code---if I don't use `\MakeRobust{\see}` would I have to put a `\protect` somewhere?

Comment: @mlchristians No. That’s just to get `\see` written out in the `.toc` file, instead of its expansion.